# How to suppress the code but have the plots displayed in R markdown?

Tags: r, plot, knitr, r-markdown

I have a very long plot code written out in R markdown. I do not want the code to be displayed, but I want to the graphs to be displayed.

I used [this](http://kbroman.org/knitr_knutshell/pages/Rmarkdown.html) advice and have this in my R chunk

`````
```{r, include=FALSE, results="hide", fig.width=8, fig.height=6}
x = c(1:10)
y = c(40:50)
plot(x~y)
````
`````

However, this simply does not give any output on the knitted file. Any suggestions?

Comment: also note that you have a y variable that is longer than your x variable. the plot() function will complain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `echo=FALSE`, neither `results="hide"` nor `include=FALSE` in your chunk options (I think the latter is your real problem). (As @markdly comments below, that means `{r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}` are the options you want to use.)

Comment: That is, `{r, echo=FALSE, fig.width=8, fig.height=6}` should do the trick